# Doit-on utiliser le terme « corrigeable » ou « corrigible » ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, adjectifs

Je me demande si l'on doit utiliser le terme « corrigeable » ou « corrigible ». L'un des deux est-il incorrect ? Si oui, lequel doit-on utiliser ?

De prime abord, j'ai l'impression que les deux sont corrects mais sans certitude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D'après le CNRTL, [corrigible](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/corrigible) s'emploie pour une personne, et [corrigeable](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/corrigeable) pour un objet.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. Est-ce une règle qui doit être utilisée dans tous les cas ?

Comment: @Zistoloen: J'aurais tendance à dire oui, mais il doit bien se trouver des exceptions que je n'ai pas sous la main.

Answer (score 2):

Il me semble que j'emploierais « corrigible » uniquement pour des personnes ou leurs défauts physiques ou moraux et « corrigeable » plus largement.  Cette impression est partiellement conforté par l'entrée du TLFi pour [corrigible](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/corrigible), mais les entrées pour [corrigeable](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/corrigeable) et [correctible](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/corrigible) (qu'au contraire de corrigeable je n'utiliserais lui que quand « corrigible » me semble impossible) laissent à désirer pour avoir une confirmation plus globale.

Dans la série, il y a aussi [amendable](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/amendable) dont l'usage me semble plus varié que ce que le TLFi indique.

Answer (score 1):

Les deux sont en effet corrects. Le TLF contient les deux entrées "[corrigible](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/corrigible)" et "[corrigeable](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/corrigeable)" et les définit comme "Qui peut être corrigé".

[Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/corrigeable) contient aussi les deux entrées et précise que:

> Il y a eu tendance à privilégier soit corrigible, soit corrigeable, selon les époques ; encore actuellement, on trouve des dictionnaires courants qui ne mentionnent que l’un ou que l’autre.

Néanmoins, corrigible semble être plus utilisé que corrigeable:

[image: Google Ngram Viewer]

Answer (score 1):

Les deux sont corrects et je les comprends comme synonymes même si tous les dictionnaires ne sont pas d'accords. Le plus courant semble être *corrigible*, d'après [le ngram d'Otiel](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6757/82)
[image: Ngram *corrigeableù vs. *corrigible*], mais c'est peut-être un cas d'hypercorrection : *corrigeable* a tendance à sonner un peu trop facile pour être… correct. Note qu'il existe aussi [correctible](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/correctible) qui est plus rare et risque de sonner plus pédant.